# Change tabstop in TextEdit.app

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, text-editor, textedit

How does one change the tabstop in TextEdit.app for Snow Leopard?

The current tabstop is *8* spaces. I would like to change this to *4* spaces.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

1. Make sure `Format > Text > Show Ruler` is enabled.
2. Locate the tab stops in the ruler (Fig. 1).
3. Move the first one to 1/4 inch (Fig. 2).

[image: Fig1] [image: Fig2]
Alternatively, you could use something like Keyboard Maestro, TextExpander, or BetterTouchTool to map four spaces to the Tab key. This is the only way I'm aware of to do it for plain text files (`.txt`).

Comment: If your document has existing content, select all of the content before making this adjustment so the tab stops are applied to all of the paragraphs.

Comment: This works for rich text documents. It seems not to show a ruler for plain text documents. I'll keep this in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't realize it didn't work for .txt files. Oh well!

Comment: @phwd Added an alternative for .txt files. :)

Comment: Sweet looking into them now

Answer (score 32):

For plaintext tabs, you don't need to replace the entire TextEdit app to change it. I looked at the source code and it provides the simpler answer: Open the Terminal and type

`defaults write com.apple.TextEdit "TabWidth" '4'`

Where '4' is the number of spaces a tab should be.

Comment: Fantastic, I basically only use it in plaintext mode anyways. Would upvote more if I could :)

Comment: Nice! Worked perfectly!

Comment: this should be a selected answer.

Comment: @liquid, You looked at the source code? Textedit is opensource?

Comment: @Pacerier To ensure this comment stays up to date... Google is your friend. TextEdit is available as sample code directly from Apple.

Comment: Why in the world is the default 8 spaces? That seems way to large in my opinion. The default should be 4. Does anyone else agree? I'd be curious to know what other people think.

Answer (score 1):

A kindly soul has slightly **modified TextEdit** to add a field, "Tab Width", at the bottom of the "New Document" tab of the "Preferences" window.

Type in a number between 1 and 100 (inclusive) and it will change the width of tabs to that number (in character widths).

Download at **[code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/textedit-with-tabwidth/).**

Since I couldn't replace the main TextEdit app, **I used "show package contents" and replaced the inside of the app**.